# Is it possible to use less number of iBeacons to map out the location of rooms?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

Is it possible for me to map out locations of rooms in a building using less number of iBeacons than the number of rooms itself? For example if i have 5 rooms, can i use 3 iBeacons instead to map out all the rooms precisely?

if it's possible, what is the least number of this beacons should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this with less beacons. A beacon will provide you with a unique identifier for each room, so unless you have a third component that you can use to identify a room, you wouldn't be able to group them.

If your question refers to using the same UUID for all beacons, then yes, you could use the minor and major values to uniquely identify a room, if two rooms have the same UUID

Comment: I am creating an app, basically i want the users to be able to select the room they want to visit, and the app shows them where it is. How is it possible to use same UUID to identify room? and What "minor and major values" are you referring to? Thanks :)

Comment: From what you comment, I believe this is the wrong technology for this scenario. A beacon will allow you to tell your user if they are within a certain distance or proximity from a beacon. If from your app, your user can select the room they want to go to, they wont know where the room is unless they are in proximity to the beacon.Even If you are trying to do RTLS, doing so with beacons will be very challenging and inaccurate. Minor and major are values broadcasted by the beacons, which can be used to identify a beacon's region.

Comment: So what u are trying to say is, if  #beacons < #rooms, it is very unlikely to work right? But how if i decide to use equal number of beacons as the rooms? Is it still possible to use this technology?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if you use any number of beacons, selecting a room in the app based on a beacon location will be difficult to achieve. You can have the user select a room, then have the app notify the user if he is IN the room or NEAR the room. You say "then the app shows them where it is" The app will only know if its near a beacon, or if its not. Not where the beacon is.

Comment: Last question, if i use the beacons to identify where the users are, whereas the map of the room is hardcoded. Is it possible to achieve this app? Thanks so much once again

Comment: It might be, but that sounds more like an RTLS system, which means you would need something more complex